# Gradle tests report for Android Tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Can I have gradle tests report for android tests? I want to have the report directly in the terminal. Every time a test is passed, failed or skipped I want to have the report printed in the terminal with the name of the test and the status.

For Unit tests I can add this to the gradle file to have the reports:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

I didn't find any solution to the android tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (add to app/library `build.gradle`)

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AndroidTestTask) { task ->
    task.doFirst {
        logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
    }
    task.doLast {
        logging.level = LogLevel.LIFECYCLE
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what this code is supposed to do but as far as "I want to have the report printed in the terminal with the name of the test and the status." asked by Sandro Machado this is not working. Unless there's more configuration that is needed.

Comment: It basically tells Gradle to output the result of androidTest tests to the terminal, we use it in several projects and see tests results in the output of the build.

Comment: I checked out the basic Espresso sample from Google -- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/BasicSample -- and then added the lines there. Running `./gradlew cC` doesn't make any test be printed on the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: I cloned your repo -- https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters -- and I ran `./gradlew cC` there .. Nothing on the console. As I said on my answer with or without the workaround running with `--info` will print the tests. BTW, nice article about quality!

Comment: Haha, thanks :) As you can see here https://travis-ci.org/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/builds/104003598 in the end of output there are androidTest results, so it definitely works with Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin versions in the #qualitymatters. Can you please check if change of Gradle or Android Gradle Plugin in your projects helps?

Comment: This just doesn't seem to work. See this example as well: https://github.com/skoric/QuoteBox/blob/master/build.gradle#L81

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin It does not work in your CI example anymore: https://travis-ci.org/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters#L2280.

Comment: @JaredBurrows uh, too bad, thanks for noticing. I don't know a solution for now, but I can suggest you try Spoon (with Gradle Plugin if you want) which definitely does print test execution information.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug filed to the Platform tools team that is still not resolved:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182307

You can vote it to help. The workaround didn't work for me, but if you use Gradle Plugin >= 1.5.0 you can run the command with info logs enabled like this:

`./gradlew cC --info`

and then you'll see the tests being printed with **no extra configuration**.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into `app/build/reports/tests/debug/index.html` or `app/build/test-results/`?

By using the [new test support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html) you should find your reports there, with no extra-configuration needed.

Comment: I know that, but I want to have the report directly in the terminal. Every time a test is passed, failed or skipped I want to have the report printed in the terminal with the name of the test and the status.

Comment: Ok, then please update your question to include that info as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some investigation, and universal variant to show unitTests and AndroidTests in the terminal is put '--debug' option on the gradle terminal command.

Example:

`./gradlew cleanTestDebugUnitTest testDebugUnitTest cleanConnectedDebugAndroidTest connectedDebugAndroidTest --debug`